# Why did my code break when I added the color attribute in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

for some reason, nothing is showing in my code even though I wanted it to draw 9999(for testing reasons) rectangles.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const vertexCode = `
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 col;

void main() {
  col = color;
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fragmentCode = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 col;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if(!gl) {
  console.log("WebGL not supported");
}
const projectionMatrix = [
  2/width, 0, 0, 0,
  0, -2/height, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  -1, 1, 0, 1
];


const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexCode);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentCode);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);

gl.useProgram(program);

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
const colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, `color`);
const projectionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, `matrix`);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
const vertex = [
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1
  ]
const floatArray = new Float32Array(vertex);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
const color = [
  1, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1
]
const colorArray = new Float32Array(color);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation, false, projectionMatrix);
function rect(x, y, w, h) {
  floatArray[0] = x;
  floatArray[1] = y;
  floatArray[4] = x + w;
  floatArray[5] = y;
  floatArray[8] = x;
  floatArray[9] = y + h;
  floatArray[12] = x + w;
  floatArray[13] = y + h;

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

}
function fill(r, g, b, a) {
  colorArray[0] = r;
  colorArray[1] = g;
  colorArray[2] = b;
  colorArray[3] = a;
  // gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
let lastTime = 0;
let fpsText = document.getElementById("fps");
function animate(currentTime) {
  fpsText.textContent = (1000 / (currentTime - lastTime)).toFixed(1);
  lastTime = currentTime;
  for(let i=0;i<9999;i++) {
    fill(random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1);
    rect(random(0, 800), random(0, 600), 10, 10);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function random(low, high) {
  return low + Math.random() * (high-low)
}
```

So everything was working fine when I did not include the color attribute. However, things start breaking when I put in the code `gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);` and nothing showed on the canvas. Can you guys help me find my error? Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I get a clear error in the JavaScript console

> [.WebGL-0x7fae86814200]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

Looking at your code you need to bind the correct buffer before calling `gl.bufferData` to upload the data

You had this

```
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

but it needs to be this

```
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const vertexCode = `
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 col;

void main() {
  col = color;
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fragmentCode = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 col;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if(!gl) {
  console.log("WebGL not supported");
}
const projectionMatrix = [
  2/width, 0, 0, 0,
  0, -2/height, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  -1, 1, 0, 1
];


const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexCode);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentCode);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);

gl.useProgram(program);

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
const colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, `color`);
const projectionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, `matrix`);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
const vertex = [
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1
  ]
const floatArray = new Float32Array(vertex);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
const color = [
  1, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1
]
const colorArray = new Float32Array(color);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation, false, projectionMatrix);
function rect(x, y, w, h) {
  floatArray[0] = x;
  floatArray[1] = y;
  floatArray[4] = x + w;
  floatArray[5] = y;
  floatArray[8] = x;
  floatArray[9] = y + h;
  floatArray[12] = x + w;
  floatArray[13] = y + h;

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

}
function fill(r, g, b, a) {
  colorArray[0] = r;
  colorArray[1] = g;
  colorArray[2] = b;
  colorArray[3] = a;
  //gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
let lastTime = 0;
let fpsText = document.getElementById("fps");
function animate(currentTime) {
  fpsText.textContent = (1000 / (currentTime - lastTime)).toFixed(1);
  lastTime = currentTime;
  for(let i=0;i<9999;i++) {
    fill(random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1);
    rect(random(0, 800), random(0, 600), 10, 10);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function random(low, high) {
  return low + Math.random() * (high-low)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<div id="fps"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @gman is almost working, we just need to modify it a bit.

Here is working jsfiddle: [click](https://jsfiddle.net/bk4qyunz/).

My changes:

```js
function rect(x, y, w, h) {
  floatArray[0] = x;
  floatArray[1] = y;
  floatArray[4] = x + w;
  floatArray[5] = y;
  floatArray[8] = x;
  floatArray[9] = y + h;
  floatArray[12] = x + w;
  floatArray[13] = y + h;

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

}
function fill(r, g, b, a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    colorArray[0 + i*4] = r;
    colorArray[1 + i*4] = g;
    colorArray[2 + i*4] = b;
    colorArray[3 + i*4] = a;
  }
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

```js
function animate(currentTime) {
  fpsText.textContent = (1000 / (currentTime - lastTime)).toFixed(1);
  lastTime = currentTime;
  for(let i=0;i<999;i++) {
    fill(random(0, 1), random(0, 1), random(0, 1), 1);
    rect(random(0, 800), random(0, 600), 20, 20);
  }
  setTimeout(() => requestAnimationFrame(animate), 500); // SLOW!
}
```

```cpp
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = col;
}
```

1. I've moved a `colorBuffer` setter to `fill` function.
2. We need 4 color values, not one (because we are drawing rectangles with 4 vertices), so I've added a `for` loop to `fill` function.
3. I've reduced rectangles count to 999, increased the size to 20x20 - this is just for better picture :)
4. I need to slow rectangles drawer for a bit, so I've added `setTimeout` to reduce the framerate. If you need the maximum FPS, just use common `requestAnimationFrame(animate)` instead of my `SLOW!` line.
5. Fragment shader should use a color from vertex shader.